# background image from linked css won't show

Tags: html, css

While working on my HTML layout and tweaking my CSS in the head of my document the following worked fine:

```
html{background:url("gfx/green_tile.gif");}
```

Then I moved my CSS to a linked stylesheet in my css folder.

Here's my file structure

- index.html
- gfx

  - green_tile.gif
- css

  - custom.css

Note: I've tried the following too

```
html{background:url("../gfx/green_tile.gif");}

html{background-image:url(...);}
```

Comment: Have you tried `//gfx/green_tile.gif`? Perhaps it is best to check your browser's inspector to look for 404 errors when loading the tile image. For completeness, try disable cache too while testing.

Comment: The situation resolved after a few minutes and refreshes. Strange to me. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the stylesheet is custom.css then `html{background:url("../gfx/green_tile.gif");}` should work. This stuff happens to me all the time. Usually it's because I spelled something wrong or I didn't put enough `../`

Try putting the absolute path `http://domain.com/gfx/green_tile.gif` and see if that works. Not a permanent solution but it should help debug it, to make sure the picture is properly loading.